# How to add a custom gradle plugin to Intellij Idea?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, intellij-plugin

I created a simple gradle plugin according to [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:writing_a_simple_plugin).

```
 class MyBuild implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task("test") {
            doLast{
                println 'Yeaaa boy!'
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: MyBuild
```

But the plugin does not appear at the Idea Gradle toolar:
[image]

I have also tried to add the following code, but it does not make any diffirence:

```
idea {
    project {
        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = '1.8'
    }
    apply plugin: MyBuild
}
```

What should I do to make it appear there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you expect to see there? For example, I see the custom task, that the plugin adds here, in Gradle tool window:

[image]

Comment: OH MY! I have no idea how it was happened. Looks like I expected to see a new task in another folder... But I should just took a look at "other" folder. Thanks!